Validate if the data points are from a given distribution
I have a KDE object which is computed using 5000 training data points (3-dimensional). The KDE is computed using Statsmodel.
I have 35 test data points (also 3 dimensional).
Data for MWE:

Training Data KDE File: GitHub Link
35 Test data points: Github Link

Question: How do I validate whether the 35 test data points are from the given KDE? I am thinking of using Kolmogorov–Smirnov test for this, but the common implementations (such as in Scipy, statsmodel etc) are for 1D. Furthermore, I am confused if I should use a ks_2samp test for individual dimensions as done in the MWE below. Performing ks_2samp test is easier to implement but not sure if this is the correct way to do the validation. Or if I should compute marginal CDFs and compare them (computing them on a large grid takes too long).
MWE:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import joblib


# load training KDE (computed using 5000 data points)
training_kde = joblib.load(r"PATH-TO-DOWNLOADED_GITHUB-FILE/training_data_kde.pkl")
training_kde_df = pd.DataFrame(training_kde.data, columns=['x', 'y', 'size'])
training_kde_df['DataType'] = 'Training'

# load test data
import pandas as pd

test_data_df = pd.read_csv(r"PATH-TO-DOWNLOADED_GITHUB-FILE/test_data_points.csv", names=['x', 'y', 'size'], header=0)
test_data_df['DataType'] = 'Test'

# combined data
combined_data = pd.concat([training_kde_df, test_data_df], ignore_index=True)

# plot the KDEs to compare
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.kdeplot(data=combined_data, x='x', hue='DataType', common_norm=False)
plt.title('KDE comparison for X-dimension')


# Perform KS test
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp
x_statistic, x_pvalue = ks_2samp(training_kde_df['x'], test_data_df['x'])
y_statistic, y_pvalue = ks_2samp(training_kde_df['y'], test_data_df['y'])
size_statistic, size_pvalue = ks_2samp(training_kde_df['size'], test_data_df['size'])

if x_pvalue > 0.05 and y_pvalue > 0.05 and size_pvalue > 0.05:
    print("The test data is drawn from the same distribution")


plt.show()
print



Neither scipy nor statsmodels has gof tests for multivariate distributions (with the exception of binned data as in contingency tables, chisquare test and similar.)
